# Odd behavior in LINQ to SQL with anonymous objects and constant columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My colleague was getting an error with a more complex query using LINQ to SQL in .NET 4.0, but it seems to be easily reproducible in more simpler circumstances.  Consider a table named TransferJob with a synthetic id and a bit field.

If we make the following query

```
using (var ctx = DBDataContext.Create())
{
    var withOutConstant = ctx.TransferJobs.Select(x => new { Id = x.TransferJobID, IsAuto = x.IsFromAutoRebalance });
    var withConstant = ctx.TransferJobs.Select(x => new { Id = x.TransferJobID, IsAuto = true });//note we're putting a constant value in this one

    var typeA = withOutConstant.GetType();
    var typeB = withConstant.GetType();
    bool same = typeA == typeB; //this is true!

    var together = withOutConstant.Concat(withConstant);
    var realized = together.ToList();//invalid cast exception
}
```

An invalid cast exception is thrown where noted. But strangely, we have type equality when viewing in a debugger.

Simply changing the second to last line to move from IQueryable's to using linq-to-objects

```
var together = withOutConstant.ToList().Concat(withConstant.ToList());
var realized = together.ToList();//no problem here
```

then everything work fine as expected.

After some initial digging, I see that it looks like the programmers of LINQ to SQL were considering performance and are not actually having the generated SQL pull the constant value in the case with the explicit setting of true in the withConstant version.

Finally, if I switch order everything seems to work:

```
var together = withConstant.Concat(withOutConstant); //no problem this way
```

However, I'd still like to know if better detail what is really going on.  I find it rather odd that these would be considered equal types but cause an invalid cast exception.  What's actually happening under the covers?  How could I go about proving it to myself?

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Boolean()
   at Read_<>f__AnonymousType2`2(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at KBA.GenericTestRunner.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\nick\Source\Workspaces\KBA\Main\KBA\KBA.GenericTestRunner\Program.cs:line 59
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Generated SQL is the following:

```
SELECT [t2].[TransferJobID] AS [Id], [t2].[IsFromAutoRebalance] AS [IsAuto]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[TransferJobID], [t0].[IsFromAutoRebalance]
    FROM [dbo].[TransferJob] AS [t0]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t1].[TransferJobID], @p0 AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[TransferJob] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.34209
```

With the order reversed (which doesn't crash) the SQL is:

```
SELECT [t2].[TransferJobID] AS [Id], [t2].[value] AS [IsAuto]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[TransferJobID], @p0 AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[TransferJob] AS [t0]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t1].[TransferJobID], [t1].[IsFromAutoRebalance]
    FROM [dbo].[TransferJob] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.34209
```

To my earlier comment, the constant isn't pulled when doing

```
withConstant.ToList()

SELECT [t0].[TransferJobID] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[TransferJob] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.34209
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? That would give some more hints about where the problem might lie.

Comment: Could you post the class definition/model for an instance of `T` in your `IQueryable<T>`'s? Also, when you say 'synthetic id' do you mean an auto incremented in for you pk?

Comment: Please put it in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: What would happen if you used `.Select(x => new { Id = x.TransferJobID, IsAuto = 1 });` instead of using the constant `true` or `false`? Technically the SQL type is a bit, seems like the provider might have a bug/shortcoming where it doesn't know how to convert that C# into SQL when you project with a C# constant. The other things obviously just work because you're doing LINQ to Objects so no such cast occurs.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal that will not even compile since the objects will no longer have the same type, int versus bool.

Comment: Perhaps the same underlying issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982711/linq-to-sql-specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-with-union

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I think you may be onto something, however, if instead of doing this with a bit column I use a varchar or short column, there is no issue.  It does seem exclusive to how bools are treated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it's happening in this specific instance but I've empirically concluded that `get_Boolean()` is prone to breaking when implicit type conversions happen in the SQL provider. I would assume the larger difference in execution is that your breaking example is doing `IQueryable<T>.Contcat(IEnumerable<T>)` while the other two are doing `IEnumerable<T>.Contcat(IEnumerable<T>)` which means your `withConstant` never has to convert back to a SQL type.

Comment: The value `true` of type `bool` is being passed into `get_Boolean()` which is actually expecting an `int32`. Docs here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean(v=vs.110).aspx  My opinion is that this *should* work and the execution plan isn't being generated correctly. I don't have the expertise to debug further but I think your IEnum has to get converted to SQL and when it converts `true` it's not using a `bit` so when it later tries to convert the column back to a C# bool it's not passing an int into getboolean and it throws.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal you can't pass a bool to a method that expects an int. This int is the column ordinal. Unlikely that L2S is mixing data with column ordinals.

Comment: @nlh3 what's actually your intention with this question? What do you want to know? I have answered the questions that I found but at its heart this is a boring L2S bug. Not much to see here. Are you just curious?

Comment: @usr yes, it's curiosity about what is going on and seeing how others would go about doing so for my edification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During the enumeration in the `together.ToList()` constructor, we try to move to the next element in the *deferred* query, that is now *resolved*.

`MoveNext` is going to create some object from the database results.
The database query is turned into a `DataReader` and a row is extracted from the `DataReader`.
Now `get_Boolean` is implemented in a way that it does a `VerifyType` of the object and casts an exception if it is not valid.

What you are missing to show in your question is the `SqlText` of `together`'s query (as well as the `_sqlText` of your `ctx.TransferJobs`), so I'm forced to make a reasonable assumption.

TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0. Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.

The Linq to Sql Data Source will trasform the `Select` for a `true` parameter in something like

```
([table].[column] = 1)
```

and for a `false` parameter in

```
NOT ([table].[column] = 1)
```

So - when your first filter is not based on a `true` boolean condition - the above line of code is where a cast exception might come into play if the Linq Provider is getting an object that is not 0 (or what the `false` boolean corresponds to), my guess is a null.

-- *footnote* --

A helper to log the actual sql under a Linq query (besides the [Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) Property, of course)

```
Debug.WriteLine(together.ToString());
```

(or the `GetQueryText(query)` as described in the [debugging support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic37))

**UPDATE**

After having seen the SQL, a working fix is simply to map the bit field as int like below, using the [DbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype.aspx) Property

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute
(Storage="_IsFromAutoRebalance", DbType="INT NOT NULL")]
            public bool IsFromAutoRebalance
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._IsFromAutoRebalance;
                }
```

Related (old) VS feedback [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651648/linq-to-sql-union-query-with-bit-column-gives-specified-cast-is-not-valid-error) where the bug was closed as `Won't Fix` with a suggested workaround

Answer (score 5):

This is a L2S bug. This is clear from the following facts:

- It is a crash in L2S internal code. It is not a controlled/expected exception.
- This should just work.
- Random changes to the query make the crash disappear.

Modify the query in random ways until it happens to work. You already have a good workaround. Leave a C# comment to document that this query depends on a workaround to a L2S bug.

I have found probably a dozen L2S bugs over the years (when issuing unusual or complicated queries). The product is abandoned so eventually we'll all have to switch to EF. I'm reading the EF commit logs and they have query translation bugs as well.

> What's actually happening under the covers?

I cannot answer that without much investigation. It is possible to debug the L2S source code but that is a lot of work. This question is for reasons of curiosity only since you already have a workaround to this bug.

> How could I go about proving it to myself?

Proving that it is a bug? I have given some reasons above.

> it looks like the programmers of LINQ to SQL were considering performance and are not actually having the generated SQL pull the constant value in the case with the explicit setting of true in the withConstant version.

This does not seem plausible to me. If this was true I'd expect all pulled objects to have a value of `true`. I would not expect an invalid cast if that column isn't even pulled from the database as you suggest. I think this is a query translation bug.

An idea for another workaround would be:

```
IsAuto = x.IsFromAutoRebalance == x.IsFromAutoRebalance
```

Now this is no longer a constant but will always be true at runtime. The SQL Server query optimizer is capable of simplifying this code to `1`. Hopefully, L2S will no longer perform the broken rewrite.

---

Update:

From the T-SQL code you posted the bug is apparent. The parameter `@p0` is an int, not a bool. This causes the resulting column to promote to int [according to the rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx). It is int in both cases. Apparently, in one of the cases L2S tries to fetch it as a bool, in the other as an int. Fetching it as a bool doesn't work and crashes. So another workaround is converting the query to use ints (e.g. `x.IsFromAutoRebalance ? 1 : 0` and `1`).